# Oracle auditing based on user

Tags: oracle, auditing

In oracle 11g version , AUDIT ALL command does not audit dml statements based on user , Anyone please help me come out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why we have not received any inputs for the query?  Its tough to reach Oracle technical support as well.